# How can I use an account created on a webpage?

Tags: web3js, javascript, ganache

I am developing an API in javascript and one of the method calls is to register an account. I use web3.js to create an account and then I return the public and private key of this account.

Another method call is to store a number in a smart contract. The user will send their account's public key and/or private key (open for suggestion) and the number they want to store. Using this the API will make a transaction from their keys and store the number in a smart contract.

So far I am able to generate the account and return the keys however when I try to deploy a contract using their keys I get the message "account not recognised". I am using Ganache for the test net.

How can I make a transaction using their account keys?

Answer (score 1):

When you're making a transaction in web3, whether that is deploying a smart contract or calling an existing contract's function, your `send()` needs to include the `from` address.  This address is included in the return object from your [account create](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create).  When you include the address in the web3 call, it will automatically look for the associated private key within Ganache.

Your question is a little unclear about whether you're trying to deploy a new contract or make a transaction to one that already exists, but everything you need for either is contained in the object returned from the account create.